# If oil sank in water, how would that affect ocean life?

Tags: gravity, ocean

If oil sank in water, how could/would that affect Benthic zones?

That's all,

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please take a look at the [help] to understand what we expect from a well asked question. And also don't rush to accept the first answer you get. If you are really aiming for quality answer, wait and give time to all users to give a look at your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I will do my best to improve.

Comment: Asking specifically about the Benthic zone was a good idea. However, without more detail, we don't know if we should address the effects on currents, thermal transmission, laying data cables, climate, deep sea divers, the interaction between zones, Japanese fishing, international maritime law... can you see my point? You told us *where* you wanted your analysis, but you didn't tell us *what* you wanted analyzed. Regrettably, "everything" means writing books... and that's beyond the site's scope. I think this is an interesting question, so I'm hoping you'll add more detail.

Comment: Also, while you might be happy with the one answer you received, I really hope you'll edit your question so it can be reopened. I think this would be an interesting question for a lot of people and you might be surprised by the answers you receive.

Comment: Thank you @JBH I am thinking about how I may refine my question. Some time will probably pass before I have time to work on this catastrophe, but I do intend on following through. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***But the problem just goes away...***

I'm assuming you are asking about oil spills. Coral reefs are shallow-water formations. If (crude?) oil were heavier than water, it would sink and affect coral less (unless it sank and coated every surface). Spills would be higher impact at the sight, but spread less because it wouldn't float, instead tending to sink to the deepest depth. Shorelines would be significantly less affected by oil spills. Deep ocean life would be harmed, but crude oil would likely harden into a solid at the temps and pressures of depth and might not be so bad (?). It might even enrich the environment, but that's pure speculation. It depends on how petroleum-digesting bacteria would respond to the deep ocean conditions. It would mean oil spills would affect people less, so environmental restrictions would probably be less strict. Since it would be heavy and stay in place, it would be recoverable from the bottom, possibly even pooling like a deep ocean version of lakes and ponds.

It's a little hard to anticipate, because the chemistry of crude oil would need to be significantly different. I'll assume it's still hydrophobic, but it might be more or less soluble. Something (heavy metals?) would need to be added to significantly increase the density and mass. If crude oil was bound to significant amounts of heavy metal, it would be a serious environmental issue. Again, it's purely conjecture. Something like glycerol is denser than water, but it's also soluble in water.

A lot would depend on the chemistry of the resulting compound.

Comment: Thank you! your answer was VERY helpful. I don't know why they closed the question... Anyway, thank you again!

Comment: @Traveler The question was closed because it needs more context. There are a myriad of ways oil can get into bodies of water. Which case you want analyzed? "All of them" is a bit much for this site. This is demonstrated by how this answer starts with *"I'm assuming..."*. If you can edit the question to be more focused, it would probably get re-opened and/or get upvotes, and you might get more answers.

Comment: There are bacteria eating the iron of the Titanic,  I don't know if there are any eating the coal.  Jet-A1 supports life, it's possible that crude can too.

Comment: @Jasen I actually did a paper on this in grad school. Yes, there are bacteria that digest almost every part of crude oil (slowly), but I'm not sure they can all live under deep sea conditions.

Comment: There are anerobic coal-eating bacteria so anerobic crude-oil eating bacteria are plausible but in the deep see methane clathrates may choke the process.